# Error:dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: package-management, software-center, dependencies

I'm a new Ubuntu user, and I don't know so much about this system. So, when I tried to install a game (Lonely Survivor) I got this error:

```
"Error: dependency is not satisfiable: ia32-libs(>=20080808)"
```

I've tried to install with the older ubuntu software center, (I'm using 16.04 LTS and it has a bug so I had to install the older software center) and with `GDebi` Package Installer.

[image]